# Custom Unsubscribe URL for Marketing cloud not working on IOS (safari) devices

Tags: marketing-cloud, content-builder, unsubscriber, unsubscribe

We have built a custom unsubscribe URL in service cloud which we are sending to marketing cloud through an import activity and the same link will be placed on the email so that customer can use it to unsubscribe.

The custom unsubscribe link is all working fine (shows details like Email address and name of the customer) when the user clicks it on the desktop (windows), Andriod phone but fails (page still open but on name and email shows as not found) one use click it from the Apple device as their safari is the default browser.

After investigation, we found that when we send the email through user-initiated emails and clicks on the track links checkbox, then it doesn't work on IOS only but if we uncheck the tracking then it works on all the devices inc IOS.
We are working with the support team as well but we got the response that they cannot support in resolution as the URL is built outside the MC and which doesn't come under their scope as this might be an issue with the browser.
Few solutions we tried so far:

1. Stop a particular link from tracking: Solution provided at trailblazer community (https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000314602&language=en_US&type=1&mode=1) but didn’t worked
2. Add redirectto function on the unsubscribe link: Solution provided on stack exchange but unfortunately didn’t worked.

Recently we had discussed discussion with MC Architect where she mentioned to redirect you unsubscribe page through a cloud page using redirect function. We also tried it but didn’t work

Can anyone faced a similar situation and have any solution to fix it? Thanks

Comment: Didn't you post the same here before? It would help to see the link with all the passed parameters to start with

Comment: Yes but deleted that post to start fresh one. In the content, we are redirecting the subscriber towards cloud pages first 'href="%%=CloudPagesURL(0000)=%%">Afmelden' and in the cloud page we used redirect function to fetch the unique ids and below is the code%%[ 
var Int Set Int= retrievesalesforceobjects('CB_Interest__c', 'Id,  CB_ContactID__c ,CB_UnsubscribeURL__c', 'CB_ContactID__c', '=', _subscriberKey) var subscriberRow, unsubscribeurl
set subscriberRow = Row(Int, 1) set @unsubscribeurl = Field(subscriberRow, "CB_UnsubscribeURL__c")
]%% %%=Redirect(unsubscribeurl)=%%